# Получение содержимого директивы angularjs через transclude так, чтобы это содержимое не выполнялось

Tags: angularjs

Имеется некая директива, назовем ее *drc*, и допустим что она содержит другой код, например вот так:

```
<drc>
  <old-drc attr="value" />
  <new-drc attr="value" />
</drc>
```

сама директива *drc* объявлена с опцией `transclude = true`.

Директивы *new-drc* не существует на момент исполнения директивы *drc*, в то время как директива *old-drc* существует.

Мне необходимо сначала зарегистрировать директиву *new-drc* - асинхронно, а после этого выполнить весь код внутри директивы *drc*, для этого можно использовать функцию `transclude`, но тогда *new-drc* не выполняется, в целом это не проблема так как `transclude` вернет объект, который можно прогнать через сервис `$compile`, и тогда директива `transclude` выполнится, но вместе с ней еще раз (уже второй) выполнится директива *old-drc*.

Как можно получить кусок *DOM*, который находится внутри директивы *drc*, не выполняя при этом его?

Comment: добавьте код директив